# Masonry not reloading element on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

i implemented masonry into my website because i am using a grid system and it seemded the best and easiest solution to making the grid work properly. It all worked great until i added the

> `isFitWidth = true`

statement. It worked in terms of centralising the grid, however the grid no longer reloads when i resize the browser. Before as i made the browser smaller the grid elements moved underneath each other, now they only reload when i either reload the page manually, or make the browser bigger, not when i make it smaller.

Any ideas why?

JQUERY

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var $container = $('#dash_content');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
  columnWidth: 300,
  itemSelector: '.dash_content_ele',
  isFitWidth: true, 
  gutter: 35,
  isResizable: true
});
    });
</script>
```

CSS

> ```
>     #dash_content{
>
>   width: 100%;
>   margin-left: auto;
>   margin-right: auto;
>   min-height: 1000px;
>   height: auto;
>   background-color: #aaaaaa;
>
> }
>
>
>
> .dash_content_ele{
>   width: 300px;
>   min-height: 200px;
>   background-color: #ffffff;
>   border-radius: 6px;
>   height: auto;
>
>   margin-bottom: 25px;
>   float: left;
>   box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #555555;
>   position: relative;
>   background-image: url(../images/dashboard/dash_ele_background.png);
>   background-repeat: repeat;
> }
> .dash_content_ele.w2{
>   width:635px;
> }
> ```

HTML

```
<div id="dash_content">

    <div class="dash_content_ele">

        </div><!--end dash_content_ele-->               

</div><!--end dash_content-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your `.dash_content_ele` CSS to use percentage widths and not fixed widths (`width: 300px;`).

**Example**

```
.dash_content_ele {
    width: 20%;
}
```

**--EDIT--**

As suggested by Arken, you can call masonry reload within a window resize function.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#container').masonry('reloadItems');
});
```

Comment: i have to use a fixed width, one because i don't want the elements changing size and two becuase the percentage width doesn't work with isFitWidth: true, the elements collapse in on one another. Thanks tho

Comment: I see, good point. Would you mind creating a JsFiddle close to your masonry layout so I can help you with this issue?

Comment: Hi, just to let you know i fixed the issue by adding a masonry reload that is triggered via a browser resize event. Thanks tho for the help

Comment: @AfromanJ Where would the resize function go in the code in the original post?

Comment: @Desi you can place the resize function anywhere inside '$(document).ready(function() {'